# Submitting multiple records using AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I do not have much idea on jQuery/Ajax. Could someone help me to submit the forms dynamically

here is the requirement:
- I have set of tests
- Each test has a result
- Each test result stored as separate record

I am thinking of following approach: 
- display each test result as a separate form and submit each one of them using AJAX

I hope there would be a better approach, please help me

here are my code:

```
//results controller
class ResultsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @results = Result.all
  @tests = Tests.all
end

def new
  @result = Result.new
end

//view
@tests.each do |test|
  = form_for(@result) do |r|
      = r.label :test_id, test.name
      = r.hidden_field :test_id, :value => test_id
      = r.select :status, options_for_select(%w[UNTESTED PASS FAIL PENDING BLOCKED INVALID])           
    = r.submit "Submit"
```

Comment: make _test.html.erb as partial page, and on main testset page call that partial for each test. So on single page you can show all the test with it's results

Answer (score 0):

The index action from controller will call index page
In index page

```
= @tests.each do |test|
    #test.#{test.id}= render partial: "test", :locals => {test: test}
```

create one _test.html page In _test page do all this,

```
= form_for(test) do |test|
  = r.label :test_id, test.name
  = r.hidden_field :test_id, :value => test_id
  = r.select :status, options_for_select(%w[UNTESTED PASS FAIL PENDING BLOCKED INVALID])           
= r.submit "Submit"
```

create one index.js.html file

```
:plain
    $("#test_#{@test.id}").html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "test", :locals => { :test => @test}))}");
```